# Android ADT Fails to Run Project

Tags: java, android, adt

I just upgraded from Windows 8 to Windows 8.1 and found that my android ADT fails to run a project. I tried to uninstall and install my JAVA JDK several times but it did not work. Can anybody help? In the below is the log.

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

Internal Error (javaClasses.cpp:136), pid=804, tid=5796
fatal error: Invalid layout of preloaded class

JRE version:  (7.0_45-b18) (build )

Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.45-b08 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)

Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows

 If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp


---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x0000000002d6e000):  JavaThread "Unknown thread" [_thread_in_vm, id=5796, stack(0x0000000002730000,0x0000000002830000)]

Stack: [0x0000000002730000,0x0000000002830000]

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )

Other Threads:

=>0x0000000002d6e000 (exited) JavaThread "Unknown thread" [_thread_in_vm, id=5796, stack(0x0000000002730000,0x0000000002830000)]

VM state:not at safepoint (not fully initialized)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

GC Heap History (0 events):
No events

Deoptimization events (0 events):
No events

Internal exceptions (0 events):
No events

Events (10 events):
Event: 0.377 loading class 0x0000000002bcfd70 done
Event: 0.377 loading class 0x0000000002bcf790 done
Event: 0.377 loading class 0x0000000002bcf770
Event: 0.377 loading class 0x0000000002bd7870
Event: 0.377 loading class 0x0000000002bd7870 done
Event: 0.377 loading class 0x0000000002bd78a0
Event: 0.377 loading class 0x0000000002bd78a0 done
Event: 0.377 loading class 0x0000000002bd78d0
Event: 0.377 loading class 0x0000000002bd78d0 done
Event: 0.377 loading class 0x0000000002bcf770 done


Dynamic libraries:
0x00007ff6344b0000 - 0x00007ff6344e3000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe
0x00007ffedf740000 - 0x00007ffedf8e9000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x00007ffedd890000 - 0x00007ffedd9c9000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\KERNEL32.DLL
0x00007ffedcb90000 - 0x00007ffedcc9e000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x00007ffedb6f0000 - 0x00007ffedb77b000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\apphelp.dll
0x00007ffeda9c0000 - 0x00007ffedaa0c000     C:\WINDOWS\AppPatch\AppPatch64\AcGenral.DLL
0x00007ffedd9d0000 - 0x00007ffedda77000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\msvcrt.dll
0x00007ffedc8a0000 - 0x00007ffedc8cb000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\SspiCli.dll
0x00007ffedf5e0000 - 0x00007ffedf631000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
0x00007ffedd5c0000 - 0x00007ffedd731000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\USER32.dll
0x00007ffedde40000 - 0x00007ffeddfb6000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\ole32.dll
0x00007ffede1d0000 - 0x00007ffedf5df000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\SHELL32.dll
0x00007ffedc0d0000 - 0x00007ffedc0ef000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\USERENV.dll
0x00007ffedd460000 - 0x00007ffedd505000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x00007ffed4820000 - 0x00007ffed483b000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MPR.dll
0x00007ffedd0b0000 - 0x00007ffedd1e6000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x00007ffeddbc0000 - 0x00007ffeddc17000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
0x00007ffeddc20000 - 0x00007ffedddf7000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\combase.dll
0x00007ffedd740000 - 0x00007ffedd885000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\GDI32.dll
0x00007ffedcac0000 - 0x00007ffedcad4000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\profapi.dll
0x00007ffedb380000 - 0x00007ffedb421000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\SHCORE.dll
0x00007ffedde00000 - 0x00007ffedde34000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x00007ffedda80000 - 0x00007ffeddbb8000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\MSCTF.dll
0x00007ffeda720000 - 0x00007ffeda97a000     C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.9600.16384_none_62475f7becb72503\COMCTL32.dll
0x0000000076dc0000 - 0x0000000076e92000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\msvcr100.dll
0x00000000765f0000 - 0x0000000076db9000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\server\jvm.dll
0x00007ffeda9b0000 - 0x00007ffeda9b9000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WSOCK32.dll
0x00007ffed4800000 - 0x00007ffed481f000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINMM.dll
0x00007ffedd3d0000 - 0x00007ffedd3d7000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\PSAPI.DLL
0x00007ffedd400000 - 0x00007ffedd458000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WS2_32.dll
0x00007ffed4520000 - 0x00007ffed454a000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINMMBASE.dll
0x00007ffedd0a0000 - 0x00007ffedd0a9000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\NSI.dll
0x00007ffedcf80000 - 0x00007ffedcfca000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\cfgmgr32.dll
0x00007ffedb970000 - 0x00007ffedb996000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DEVOBJ.dll
0x00000000765e0000 - 0x00000000765ef000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\verify.dll
0x00000000765b0000 - 0x00000000765d8000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java.dll
0x0000000076510000 - 0x0000000076545000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\jdwp.dll
0x0000000076500000 - 0x0000000076508000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\npt.dll
0x0000000076590000 - 0x00000000765a5000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\zip.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,suspend=y,address=localhost:61050 -Dfile.encoding=GBK -Xbootclasspath:C:\Users\victor\Downloads\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130729\sdk\platforms\android-18\android.jar;C:\Users\victor\Downloads\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130729\sdk\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google-18\libs\effects.jar;C:\Users\victor\Downloads\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130729\sdk\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google-18\libs\usb.jar;C:\Users\victor\Downloads\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130729\sdk\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google-18\libs\maps.jar 
java_command: com.example.android.notepad.Server
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
JAVA_HOME=C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\
PATH=C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\Condusiv Technologies\IntelliMemory\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\runtime\win64;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin
USERNAME=victor
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 58 Stepping 9, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 8 , 64 bit Build 9200 

CPU:total 8 (4 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 58 stepping 9, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, avx, aes, erms, ht, tsc, tscinvbit, tscinv

Memory: 4k page, physical 12464932k(8831336k free), swap 14365480k(9985328k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.45-b08) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.7.0_45-b18), built on Oct  8 2013 05:47:22 by "java_re" with unknown MS VC++:1600

time: Sat Oct 19 15:14:03 2013
elapsed time: 0 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

Even thought very late. My issue got sorted out by first completely Uninstalling and then Re-installing Java.